# How to get one response at a time instead of multiple responses on socket?

Tags: java, xml, sockets, tcp

I am new to Socket programming.

From client I am sending an XML message one at a time but on the server side am receiving with concatenation of next response: so if 2 responses were sent they should be received one after another but in my case I am receiving both of them together.

This is my server code:

```
 public void run() {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    OutputStream os;
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    String response = "";
    int MAX_XML_COMMAND_LEN = 9000;
    char[] clientCommand=new  char[MAX_XML_COMMAND_LEN];
    int len = 0;

    log.debug("New Client is::" + this);
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uctmSockfd.getInputStream()));
        os = uctmSockfd.getOutputStream();
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        while (m_bRunThread) {
            len = in.read(clientCommand,0,MAX_XML_COMMAND_LEN);
            if(len < 0) {
                log.debug("Failed in reading socket input stream. Possible connection close from client.Exiting the client thread\r\n");
                break;
            }
            log.debug("Data received from the client is :" + new String(clientCommand,0,len));
            response = processReceivedMessage(new String(clientCommand,0,len));
            response = response+"\n";
            bw.write(response);
            bw.flush();
        }
    }catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {
    }catch(SocketException sock_exception){
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception in client thread.",e);
    } finally {
        try {
            in .close();
            uctmSockfd.close();
            log.error("The client " + this + " is exited.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is sample xml message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config> <sendAlerts> <alertInfo alertName="User Calls to a destination pattern exceeds" timeStamp="1651073549323" eventId="210" component_name="15" eventMessage="Calls made by user 0049 ending from
     Time Period - Wed Apr 27 08:31:28 PDT 2022 to Wed Apr 27 08:32:30 PDT 2022
     exceeds the rate limit of 1
     to destinations matching rule pattern  011NXX.|XXX.|+XX.  as defined by rule khalid_vol.
     This is a possible TollFraud attempt$$$PERIOD=Wed Apr 27 08:31:28 PDT 2022 to Wed Apr 27 08:32:30 PDT 2022$$$RNAME=khalid_vol$$$RPATTERN=011NXX.|XXX.|+XX.$$$RTYPE=RATE" ack="0" eventType="2" srcContact="192.168.10.20:5060" destContact="192.168.10.6:5544" srcIP="192.168.10.20" destIP="192.168.10.6" srcExt="0049" destExt="0119646" srcDomain="n/a" destDomain="n/a" severity_level="3" protocol="SIP" comment="None" event_src="LOCAL" attackName="User Calls to a destination Pattern exceeds" method="INVITE" evCategory="1" srcCountry="INDIA" srcCity="Hyderabad" isp="ACT Fibernet" state="40" latitude="17.3846: 17.3846" longitude="78.4574: 78.4574:IN:Hyderabad" destCountry="IRAQ" callType="International" riskEnabled="false" riskScore="0" clientName="Unknown:Unknown" ruleName="khalid_vol" nwGroupName="redshift" privateField="n/a" uctmName="REDSHIFT" deviceTag="Redshift" /> </sendAlerts> </config>
```

Note: xml message encoded with new lines for few attributes

Please help how to receive above message one at time instead of concatenated messages.

Comment: Have your XML parser read directly from the socket. Don't interpose code like this. There are no message boundaries in TCP, so what you ask is unattainable. But the XML parser knows when to stop reading.

Comment: NB `(len < 0)` is not a failure, and it is not 'possibl[y]' but *definitely* a connection closure by the peer, which you don't need to log. An `IOException` is a failure. And you should not log client exit as a failure. It is a normal condition unless there was an `IOException`, which you will already have logged.

Comment: bro @user207421 is this array copying in.read(clientCommand,0,MAX_XML_COMMAND_LEN);  causing my issue

Comment: @user207421 is there a way to get first response and parse it then need to store next responses and after parse after like that any possibility there

Comment: 1. No, the entire concept of trying to read a single request is causing your issue. 2. Yes there is, and I have already provided it. Parsing the XML directly will do exactly what you want. All you have to do is eliminate code.

Comment: @user207421 yes you are right reading multiple responses into single response causing this issue. there is of response contains half xml string since char array length 9000 only so when multiple responses come it may full and get half string at the end. for that i need to check starting and ending tags then need to  parse

Comment: No you don't. You need to connect the parser directly to the socket, as I already said. It already checks start and end tags. You do not need to repeat this work or reimplement this function.

Answer (score 1):

> how to get one response at a time instead of reading multiple repsponses on socket

You can't. Things like "response" or "message" are concepts of the application. A plain TCP socket instead only knows about a byte stream without some kind of inherent message markers. This also means that multiple writes in the sender might end up with less or more reads at the recipient.

This means that instead of relying on read and write to maintain messages, you have to define an application protocol which makes it easy to know where a message starts and ends, so that you are able to extract messages from the byte stream. Typical ways are length prefixes or separators between messages.

Comment: Well, he already has XML as his application protocol. He's just not using it correctly.